# How to get back the old git diff interface?

Tags: git, diff, meld

I changed my git diff-tool to meld. This works great, but I would like some way to generate the old-style git diff (a short piece of text indicating only the relevant lines) to email a change I made to someone.

How do I go back to the old git diff tool?

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
$ git diff --no-ext-diff
```